# Tflite model maker took all the disk issue colab

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I am unable to install tflite model maker in colab. I run all the commands with Nightly also . But it didn't work now. And my project is stuck.
pip instal Tflite-model-maker didn't install it took long time and disk of colab.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue! I do not think you can do more right now but to wait to be fixed.

Comment: I have the same issue in fact when I made  "!pip install -q tflite-model-maker", normally only takes a minute, but actually runs about 18 min, and finally I stop it because I get the warning of storage from Colab. 

And the trace is very long, apparently repeats the step "Preparing metadata( setup.py)" all the time and consume the storage. Please warn when yo fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this due to a current bug with tflite-support not being able to run with Python>3.10.
You can try to use a fallback version on Google Colab (see [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60431#issuecomment-1533628479)) or use Media Pipe Solutions which is the next step of TensorFlow Lite.